# Unable to install blist using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install `blist` using pip:

```
    pip install blist
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DBLIST_FLOAT_RADIX_SORT=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c blist/_blist.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/blist/_blist.o
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’; did you mean ‘-Wunused-parameter’?
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’; did you mean ‘-Wunused-parameter’?
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for blist
      Running setup.py clean for blist
    Failed to build blist
```

I tried to install python-dev and setuptools, nothing changed
I tried to export flags:

```
    export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
    export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

with no success.

I'm using python 2.7, ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I really don't know much about this topic, but could this maybe be an actual typo in the installation?

Comment: were you able to resolve this @user3379482?

Comment: In my case, I had a small task to do, and I just wanted to use it. I used Google colab, and it worked there.. so, actually I don't know what was wrong, and I'm using now the latest version of Ubuntu